# What is the Bash file extension?

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a bash script in a text editor, what extension do I save my script as so it can run as a bash script?  I've created a script that should in theory start an ssh server. I am wondering how to make the script execute once I click on it. I am running OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Shell script doesn't require any particular extension. Just execute it as `bash myscript`

Comment: Its usually `.sh`, but the extension isn't required to exist at all. Linux is not Windows. The program that shall interpret your script is determined in its first line, that should be `#!/bin/bash`. It may even include parameters.

Comment: @anubhava How would i get my script to execute if i were just  to double click on it and not actually type " bash myscript"

Comment: @Amedeo that would be heading your file with the line `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: You should explain what is your script doing (or perhaps even show it in your question) and on what operating system and desktop environment. So please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Check my edited answer. I guess that by making your script executable your desktop might show it as a clickable application, but I am not sure of that.

Comment: No extensions: [Commandname extensions considered harmful](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful).

Comment: The question is really about having bash script executed in macos but there is no hint on this in the title or the tags?!

Comment: I feel that using just .sh - which is the a normalized convention - is not useful or at least helpful anymore given the (luckily!) wealth of shell interpreters we have nowadays. Personally if I do some scripting in Bash I give it a .bash extension, Zsh? then .zsh and if it's done in Nu shell, .nu does it. While it is true that Unix-like OS care about the type of the file to know on how to run it, not the extension, it is still helpful for us humans to know at a glance what you're dealing with. Additionally it is super fun to see how "hardcore" sysadmins get upset with this, makes my day 

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Disagreeing with the other answers, there's a common convention to use a `.sh` extension for shell scripts -- but it's not a useful convention. It's better not to use an extension at all. The advantage of being able tell that `foo.sh` is a shell script because of its name is minimal, and you pay for it with a loss of flexibility.

To make a bash script executable, it needs to have a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line at the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and use the `chmod +x` command so that the system recognizes it as an executable file. It then needs to be installed in one of the directories listed in your `$PATH`. If the script is called `foo`, you can then execute it from a shell prompt by typing `foo`. Or if it's in the current directory (common for temporary scripts), you can type `./foo`.

(An alternate form for the shebang line is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

but see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for a discussion of the pros and cons.)

Neither the shell nor the operating system pays any attention to the extension part of the file name. It's just part of the name. And by *not* giving it a special extension, you ensure that anyone (either a user or another script) that uses it doesn't have to care how it was implemented, whether it's a shell script (sh, bash, csh, or whatever), a Perl, Python, or Awk script, or a binary executable. The system is specifically designed so that either an interpreted script or a binary executable can be invoked without knowing or caring how it's implemented.

UNIX-like systems started out with a purely textual command-line interface. GUIs like KDE and Gnome were added later. In a GUI desktop system, you can typically run a program (again, whether it's a script or a binary executable) by, for example, double-clicking on an icon that refers to it. Typically this discards any output the program might print and doesn't let you pass command-line arguments; it's much less flexible than running it from a shell prompt. But for some programs (mostly GUI clients) it can be more convenient.

Shell scripting is best learned from the command line, not from a GUI.

(Some tools *do* pay attention to file extensions. For example, compilers typically use the extension to determine the language the code is written in: `.c` for C, `.cpp` for c++, etc. This convention doesn't apply to executable files.)

Keep in mind that UNIX (and UNIX-like systems) are not Windows. MS Windows generally uses a file's extension to determine how to open/execute it. Binary executables need to have a `.exe` extension. If you have a UNIX-like shell installed under Windows, you can configure Windows to recognize a `.sh` extension as a shell script, and use the shell to open it; Windows doesn't have the `#!` convention.

Comment: What I'm aiming for is what you mentioned in the fourth paragraph. Running my script when clicked on an icon that refers to it.

Comment: @Amedeo: Then it depends on your desktop environment. In the one I use (Cinnamon under Ubuntu), double-clicking on the icon for an executable script prompts me to run it in a terminal, display it in an editor, or run it without a terminal. It does this regardless of the file extension.

Comment: (Necro) If you omit the extension, you cannot then have a same-name folder. So, for instance, you have `deploy.sh` (or `deploy.bash`), and a folder, `deploy`, with additional deployment logic. If you rename the script to simply `deploy` it'll cause a name conflict. Naming either file or folder differently hurts manageability and possibly file sorting (`ls`, in editors, etc.). Of course, the shebang is - in the end - the determinant. But file extensions do have their rightful place.

Comment: @Kafoso: I don't think I've ever felt a need to have a script and a directory with the same name. If I did, I might call the directory `Deploy`, though that can cause problems when copying to a case-insensitive file system.

Comment: On a Mac, double clicking files *always* opens them in the default app. Thus it's helpful to have a `.sh` extension so that the script opens in your desired editor. If you want to run a script when double clicked, give it the `.command` extension and it'll run in Terminal when double clicked.

Comment: Many 3rd party applications rely on extension. Editor formatting is a prevalent one.

Comment: @karns: Perhaps, but at least emacs and vim are able to recognize a bash script without a file extension. I'm not sure whether they look at the `#!/bin/bash` line or the syntax of the file.

Comment: What about ls, file browsers, code editor side bars, online listings, filtering by file type, Windows, macOS? The problems with extensions are specific to invocation from the shell, and the fix is problematic elsewhere; you could get the best of both worlds by symlinking, for example, ~/bin/foo to ~/src/foo.sh.

Answer (score 26):

You don't need any extension (or you could choose an arbitrary one, but `.sh` is a useful convention).

You should start your script with `#!/bin/bash` (that first line is understood by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall), and you should make your file executable by `chmod u+x`. so if your script is in some file `$HOME/somedir/somescriptname.sh` you need to type once

```
 chmod u+x  $HOME/somedir/somescriptname.sh
```

in a terminal. See [chmod(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) for the command and [chmod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) for the syscall.

Unless you are typing the whole file path, you should put that file in some directory mentioned in your `PATH` (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) & [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html)), which you might set permanently in your `~/.bashrc` if your login shell is `bash`)

<sub>BTW, you could write your script in some other language, e.g. in Python by starting it with `#!/usr/bin/python`, or in Ocaml by starting it with `#!/usr/bin/ocaml`...</sub>

Executing your script by double-clicking (on what? you did not say!) is a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) issue and could be desktop specific (might be different with
Kde, Mate, Gnome, .... or IceWM or RatPoison). Perhaps reading [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) spec might help you getting a better picture.

<sub>Perhaps making your script executable with `chmod` might make it clickable on your desktop (apparently, [Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_%28graphics_layer%29) on MacOSX). But then you probably should make it give some visual feedback.</sub>

And several computers don't have any desktop, including your own when you access it remotely with [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

I don't believe it is a good idea to run your shell script by clicking. You probably want to be able to give arguments to your shell script (and how would you do that by clicking?), and you should care about its output. If you are able to write a shell script, you are able to use an interactive shell in a terminal. That it the best and most natural way to use a script. Good interactive shells (e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/) or perhaps a recent `bash`) have delicious and configurable [autocompletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete) facilities and you won't have to type a lot (learn to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key of your keyboard). Also, scripts and programs are often parts of composite commands (pipelines, etc...).

PS. I'm using Unix since 1986, and Linux since 1993. I never started my own programs or scripts by clicking. Why should I?

Comment: what do you mean by desktop specific?

Comment: Double clicking on my script

Comment: But I cannot understand why you believe it will appear on your desktop

Comment: Okay, so I have created my script in a text editor. I save the file to my desktop. When i click on my script thats saved on my desktop I want it to actually run upon me clicking on it.

Comment: I don't know what is your desktop (KDE, Gnome, MATE, ...). I strongly invite you to use the command line in a terminal, especially to run your scripts (you probably want to give them some arguments; how would you do that on the desktop?). If you are able to code a shell script you should be able to use the shell interactively in a terminal

Comment: My point is that if you are coding a shell script you should take the habit of using a command line in a terminal.

Comment: I understand that, its for a project I'm working. I want the script to execute once clicked on. Im trying to avoid using terminal to run the script.

Comment: But on what desktop? You did not say!

Comment: If by desktop you mean what computer I'm running it on? Im running it on a Macbook Air

Comment: I have links to wikipages on several terms.

Comment: I am still not aware of how to find what desktop environment I am using

Comment: after reading your answer again, I very much understand that you should run bash scripts through terminal but thats not the point. I'm not trying to find a way to run a bash script anymore. I am specifically asking if you can run scripts by clicking on them (for a project i am working on) and In the script I'm not asking it to output anything. I just want to execute the commands I wrote in the script by clicking on the script. nothing graphical has to appear.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Typically the "desktop" shows files located in the `$HOME/Desktop` directory.

Comment: Maybe not on MacOSX, and some French-localized Linux distributions use `$HOME/Bureau` instead of `$HOME/Desktop`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Could you please give me a detailed explanation on how to use chmod to possibly make my script executable.

Comment: @Amedeo: you need to take hours to learn more about scripting. We can't give you one by one each step.

Comment: When I tried to use the chmod to convert the script to executable, no changes are made to my actual script i see no executable script

Comment: You need a lot more reading. `chmod` does not do any conversion. It justs flags a file as executable. Go to a library and read some good books.

Comment: I'd use `chmod +x` rather than `chmod u+x`, unless there's a specific reason to restrict executability to the owner.

Comment: For others on linux wanting to run a script by double-clicking, Here's an answer for Nautilus: https://askubuntu.com/a/286651/974740 Summary: Open Nautilus preferences (clicking the icon in the top-left corner for me), Select 'Behavior' tab, Select "Ask each time" under "Executable Text Files". Also instead of using chmod you can right-click on the file, Select 'Properties', Select 'Permissions' tab, Check "Allow executing file as program".

Answer (score 7):

just `.sh`.

Run the script like this:

```
./script.sh
```

EDIT: Like anubhava said, the extension doesn't really matter. But for organisational reasons, it is still recommended to use extensions.

Comment: If you're running a script, you generally have no reason to care what it's written in. A bash script and a binary executable are executed the same way. Adding a `.sh` suffix to an executable script is generally useless clutter.

Comment: yes, but as i said in my edit - it is a convention to organize scripts - not more?!

Comment: I do see a lot of scripts with a `.sh` extension (and fewer with a `.bash` extension), but I'm not convinced it's at all useful. If I name a script `foo.sh` and I later decide to reimplement it in Perl, I can either change the name (and edit everything that uses it) or leave it with a misleading extension. If I name it `foo`, I don't have that problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson I can think of a use myself, I *do* care what the script is written in. I can't speak for Perl, but I would care very much if a script is written in Python or Bash. I can generally assume a Bash script will work no matter what, but Python scripts have dependencies, and Python 2 and Python 3 aren't compatible with each other. I also think it's important to differentiate between compiled binaries and scripts (which would both have no extensions), because they have different dependency needs (e.g., a binary might need libraries and be compiled for AMD64 and only work on that).

Comment: @jrh Sure, sometimes it matters (and you can tell by running `head -1 script.foo` or `file script.foo`). But if everything is installed and configured correctly, 99% of the time I just want the command to do what it's supposed to do. For me, that doesn't justify having to be aware of a `.py` or `.bash` suffix every time I run it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old now but I feel like this adds to what the question was asking for.

If your on a mac and you want to be able to run a script by double clicking it you need to use the `.command` extension. Also same as before make file executable with `chmod -x`.

As was noted before, this isn't really that useful tbh.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR -- If the user (not necessarily the developer) of the script is using a GUI interface, it depends on what file browser they are using. MacOS's Finder will require the `.sh` extension in order to execute the script. Gnome Nautilus, however, recognizes properly shebanged scripts with or without the `.sh` extension.

I know it's already been said multiple times the reasons for and against using an extension on bash scripts, but not as much why or why not to use extensions, but I have what I consider to be a good rule of thumb.

If you're the type who hops in and out of bash and using the terminal in general or are developing a tool for someone else who does not use the terminal, put a `.sh` extension on your bash scripts. That way, users of that script have the option of double-clicking on that file in a GUI file browser to run the script.

If you're the type who primarily does all or most of your work in the terminal, don't bother putting any extension on your bash scripts. They would serve no purpose in the terminal, assuming that you've already set up your `~/.bashrc` file to visually differentiate scripts from directories.

Edit:

In the Gnome Nautilus file browser with 4 test files (each with permissions given for the file to be executed) with stupidly simple bash command to open a terminal window (`gnome-terminal`):

1. A file with NO extension with `#!/bin/bash` on the first line.

   It worked by double-clicking on the file.
2. A file with a `.sh` extension with `#!/bin/bash` on the first line.

   It worked by double-clicking on the file.
3. A file with NO extension with NO `#!/bin/bash` on the first line.

   It worked by double-clicking on the file...technically, but the GUI gave no indication that it was a shell script. It said it was just a plain text file.
4. A file with a `.sh` extension with NO `#!/bin/bash` on the first line.

   It worked by double-clicking on the file.

However, as Keith Thompson, in the comments of this answer, wisely pointed out, relying on the using the `.sh` extension instead of the bash shebang on the first line of the file (`#!/bin/bash`) it could cause problems.

Another however, I recall when I was previously using MacOS, that even properly shebanged (is that a word?) bash scripts without a `.sh` extension could not be run from the GUI on MacOS. I would love for someone to correct me on that in the comments though. If this is true, it would prove that there is a least one file browser out there where the `.sh` extension matters.

Comment: Which GUI file browser do you use (or, more relevantly, what do your users use)? Does it use the extension to decide how to run a script?

Comment: Well, the platform that I have the most experience on is MacOS. In Finder, the user decides which apps to associate with what extension.
Now, I'm on Linux using Gnome, but I haven't got around to experimenting how Gnome's Nautilus file browser interacts with files with no extension yet.

Comment: If you have an executable script with a `.sh` suffix and `#!/bin/bash` on the first line, is a GUI file browser going to use `sh` to invoke it (ignoring the shebang)? If so, that could cause some problems. (The answer could be different for different browsers.)

Comment: Good points there. I've updated my answer above with some actual testing I did just now.

Comment: Interesting, but ... You said it "worked". For each of the 4 test cases, it would be good to know whether it invoked it with `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` (the latter is the default for a script with no shebang). If `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash` (which is fairly common) then you can tell by looking at the value of `$0`. (Also, if bash is invoked as `sh` it sets `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y`.)

Comment: That's interesting. My personal takeaway from this is to always include both a shebang in my scripts and a `.sh` extension because the only downside is that it takes up 3 more characters. And I'm all for avoiding ambiguity wherever possible.

Comment: The question is, if the script's name has a `.sh` suffix, does the GUI execute it with `/bin/sh` or with `/bin/bash`? If it uses bash-specific features and it's invoked with `/bin/sh`, it might break. And if the GUI pays attention to the shebang, you could have a Perl script called `foo.sh`. Why specify the interpreter inconsistently in two different ways?