# Bash: Syntax error near unexpected token `<' in done

Tags: bash

I am using the below script to read the values of the 3rd column of the CSV file. However, I am getting a Syntax error.

```
tr -d '\r' < p_test.csv > fixed_p_test.csv
while IFS="," read -r rec1 rec2
do
  echo "Displaying Record-$rec1"
  echo "Price: $rec2"

done < <(cut -d "," -f1,3 fixed_p_test.csv | tail -n +2)
```

While running the above script I am getting the below error:

```
pScanFinal.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

pScanFinal.sh: line 9: `done < <(cut -d "," -f1,3 fixed_p_test.csv | tail -n +2)'
```

My p_test.csv look like:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.158 | True | 12 | HT | Open |
| 254.658 | False | 58 | SM | Closed |

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: is your shebang `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you sure you're using bash to invoke it? I don't get a syntax error on my system, and `shellcheck` is happy with it.

Comment: You aren't actually running the script with `bash`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I am running it using "sh pScanFinal.sh"

Comment: you should update the question to show the expected output

Comment: since it's closed, here's my one-liner solution without needing to pre-clean \r or use  [ while read ] :  mawk 'NF= 2 * ( _ * ($2 = $(sub("\r?$",  _ )))) ^ (FNR == !+( $!_  = "Displaying Record " $3 ))' FS=',' OFS='\nPrice: ' p_test.csv
………….Displaying Record 12
………….Price: 192.158
………….Displaying Record 58
………….Price: 254.658..… This works cuz it's trying to evaluate NF = 2 * 0 ^ (FNR==1), 1st row evaluates NF = 2 * 0^1 -> NF = 2* 0 -> NF=0, so nothing gets printed , otherwise it's NF = 2 * 0^0 -> NF= 2*1 -> NF=2. It needs to be "2" because I'm using half of the text as OFS.

Comment: The usual way to run a Bash script is to (a) make sure the first line is `#!/bin/bash`; (b) make sure the script file is executable (`chmod +x ...`) and (c) invoke the script itself: `pScanFinal.sh`, not `sh pScanFinal.sh`. (And if your script depends on Bash features, naming it with `.sh` is misleading. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824204/827263

Comment: < continuing my own comment … > another variation of that idea but shifting items around would be mawk 'NF *= ( ( $( ($2 = $(sub(/[\r]?$/, _ ) ) )^ _ ) = "Displaying Record "$(NF=3) )^!--NF ) < FNR' FS=',' OFS='\nPrice: '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `jq` is tagged (yet I don't know why), here's how to do it with `jq`.

Input and output should be read (`-R`) and written (`-r`) as raw text. Then split (`/`) each line by comma (`,`), and select column `[2]` (0-based).

```sh
jq -Rr '(./",")[2]' file.csv
```

```json
12
58
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YnIzy-0UX4)

---

Not asked/tagged, but imho `awk` would be more appropriate:

```sh
awk -F, '{print $3}' file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, @pmf for the awk alternative, Could you also please help me with storing the result in an array?

Comment: @Pawan An array in `jq`, in `awk` or in `bash`?

Comment: I am going with the awk alternative to fetch the column values.

Comment: To read into a `bash` array, wrap it in parens and assign it to a `bash` variable: `a=($(awk -F, '{print $3}' file.csv))`. Then `echo ${a[0]}` will output `12`, and `echo ${a[1]}` will output `58`.

Comment: To read into an `awk` array, use a length counter as index, and assign the value to the next index position: `{a[++len]=$3}`. Then `{print a[1]}` will output 12, and `{print a[2]}` will output `58`.

Comment: awk command is to extract the data. How can we insert the array into csv for each index?

Comment: @Pawan I'm not sure what "insert the array into csv for each index" means. Do you really need an (`awk` or `bash`) array after all? What is your ultimate goal? If it is a CSV file, just generate it from `jq` using `@csv`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244339/discussion-between-pawan-and-pmf).

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need `cut`, `tail`, or process substitution here, which means you can make your script POSIX compliant to match how you are running it.

```
{
    read  # Skip the first line
    while IFS=, read -r rec1 _ rec2 _; do
        ...
    done
} < fixed_p_test.csv
```

Comment: {
  read
  while IFS=, read -r rec1 _ rec2 _; done
  echo "Price: $rec2"
done
} < fixed_p_test.csv


Error occurred:

pScanFinal.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
pScanFinal.sh: line 7: `  while IFS="," read -r rec1 _ rec2 _; done'

Comment: Typo; I used `done` instead of `do` to start the loop.