# Bash command line: Is there a way to use the first parameter's value as part of second parameter?

Tags: bash, shell

I frequently make temporary backups of files by making a file with nearly the same name, e.g.:

```bash
cp /some/long/path/code.php /some/long/path/code.phpcode.php.WIP_desc
```

Is there some way to shorten this without creating an alias?

Comment: What's the objection to an alias? And have you considered defining a simple function rather than creating a script?

Comment: `code.phpcode.php.WIP_desc` Is the double filename a typo? If not, could you explain what is the rule - how does second parameter depend on the first?

Answer (score 7):

You can use brace expansion in `bash`:

```
cp /some/long/path/code.php{,.WIP_desc}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `makeFileBackup` with this content

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cp "$1" "$1.WIP_desc"
```

and then run `chmod +x makeFileBackup`.

Now you can use it as `/path/to/makeFileBackup some_file`.

---

As suggested in a command, you might want to use the above program without having to specify `/path/to/` in front of it. Two general approaches are possible:

- move `makeFileBackup` to, or create a link to it in a location that's already in `PATH`;
- add to `PATH` the location where `makeFileBackup` is; in this case, you probably still don't want it to be in `/home/yourusername` but in its own directory.

Comment: I would also suggest to copy the script to `/usr/local/bin/bkp.bash`, so that the script can be used without specifying the path to the script (assuming `/usr/local/bin` is in `PATH`, which should be the default)

Comment: No reason to add any kind of `.bash` or `.sh` extension to the script once it has the execute permission bit set. It is even discouraged.

Comment: @LéaGris, I know there's no need, but I like to know (or being given a hint of) what language is used in the script. But if it is discouraged, then I'll probably remove it. What is the source of this claim?

Comment: @Enlico https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813563/what-is-the-bash-file-extension http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ cited here https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide

Answer (score 0):

Is creating a variable ok?

```
p=/some/long/path
cp $p/code.php $p/code.phpcode.php.WIP_desc
```

Double quote the expansion if `p` may contain white space.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason not to quote it.

Comment: @Enlico There's also no reason to quote it, when it is known not to contain white space, as is the case here. Quoting does add 4 more characters, with 4 chances to mistype and 4 chances to mess up quote balancing for a one-shot command. Like so often, it is a judgement call (or personal preference). When scripting though, it is always a good idea to quote your parameter expansions.

Comment: We don't know that. We have a *sample* path that doesn't contain any whitespace, but future readers may try to adapt this answer to paths that *do*.

Comment: @chepner Yes we DO know that. And the answer explicitly says what to do in the other case and has been there even before the "mindless quoting" suggestion. There's no need to be holier than the pope. When future readers don't read the sentence under the gray code box then there's little hope anyway.