# How to make named pipes in bash take both command line args and user input and output them into another program?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I am currently learning how named pipes work in bash. I want to create two programs; one that takes in an argument (e.g a name) from the user and another that takes input as the code is ran (using read). The problem is that when i run the code below it doesn't work as expected. By running read.sh first and then write.sh (with an arg) the arg and the user input should be printed in the seperate terminal that is running read.sh. I want the code to print both. I have checked already and the pipe exists. When i run the code only the arg will be printed the "$input" will not be for some reason that I can't figure out. Here is the code:

read.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read user < testPipe
    read request < testPipe
    echo "$request"
    echo "received from the pipe: $user
done
```

write.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$1
while true; do 
    echo "$user" > testPipe
    read -p "Enter a request here: " request
    echo "$request" > testPipe
done
```

I tried checking the named Pipe to see if it is correct. It is. I checked to see if the code would run with just the user input and not a arg, it also does. The problem arises when i want to enter an arg and input into a named pipe and print them out in another bash script. What I expect to happen is that when i run read.sh, nothing will happen and then when i run write.sh in another seperate terminal and give it an arg (e.g. write.sh "john") it will then ask for a request which will be inputted. Then the read.sh should print them out in the first terminal. Instead again only the arg is printed without the user input.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `echo abc >testPipe` will open the pipe, write `abc` to it, and then close it.  That will cause two successive reads from it to read first `abc` and then EOF (end of file).  To avoid reading EOF you need to keep the pipe open after writing to it.  Try the programs below.

**reader**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read user
    read request
    printf '%s\n' "$request"
    printf 'received from the pipe: %s\n' "$user"
done <testPipe
```

**writer**

```
#!/bin/bash

user=$1
while true; do 
    printf '%s\n' "$user"
    read -p 'Enter a request here: ' request
    printf '%s\n' "$request"
done >testPipe
```

- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with `printf`.
- See [What is the Bash file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27813563/4154375) for an explanation of why I replaced `read.sh` with `reader` and `write.sh` with `writer`.