How to create AWK scripts with shebang that allows in-place modifications?
I want create a awk script with a shebang such that
./main.awk text.txt

performs in-place modification in text.txt. Inspired by a previous solution, I tried something like
#!/usr/bin/awk -i inplace -f

but it didn't work.

Never use a shebang to call awk, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001, and never give a Unix command a suffix such as .awk, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824204/1745001.

@EdMorton the .awk suffix seems pretty common. The discussion you mentioned about the .sh suffix does not apply to AWK scripts, at all. They are meant for different purposes.

The .awk suffix is for files that you run using awk -f foo.awk or contain awk code that is sourced  by other awk scripts, i.e. are source for the awk command to interpret, not for Unix commands you call directly that just happen to be implemented in awk. Imagine you create a command named foo.awk and in a year you decide to reimplement foo.awk in perl or a C executable - now you have to go find every other command that calls it to change foo.awk to foo.perl or foo.exe or similar which is a sign of tight coupling which makes it bad software.

Something being common doesn't make it a good idea. Not quoting variables in shell scripts, UUOC, and every other antipattern are also common.

Use /usr/bin/env with the -S option to process multiple arguments:
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -i inplace -f

See man env:
-S, --split-string=S
       process and split S into separate arguments; used to pass multiple arguments on shebang lines


-S is non-standard (but then so is -i)

The simplest would be
#/usr/bin/gawk -f

@include "inplace"
# rest of the code goes here
...

The -i or --include is just a shorthand for the @include directive.
